# Dput but for r notebooks to reproduce errors

Tags: r, rstudio, rnotebook

I am trying to borrow examples of my failures to knit in an r notebook and then provide them to students for a class. I typically brute force the solutions. However, sometimes the error messages are uninformative and I am looking for some ways to learn the source of the errors so I can give r notebooks to students that won't knit using toy data (because I generate the errors using confidential data sources) and let them diagnose the issue. Is there anything like dput for dataframes with r notebooks that make it easier to diagnose the cause of issues or give more informative error messages?

I am trying to uncover frameworks to diagnose errors in r notebooks

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. You want to share an r notebook with an error in it that prevents knitting, but without sharing the confidential data that (in interaction with the code) generated the error? Can you anonymize the data or replace it with fake data with the same problems?